# Is it possible to add a prototype property to an imported class from another module?

Tags: typescript

I want to add a prototyped function on a class of another module than mine but I can't find how to do.

```
import { MyClass } from "module"

declare module "another-module" {
    MyClass.prototype.MyFn = someFn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create an interface in a module declaration then add the prototype to the imported class.

```
import { MyClass } from "module"

declare module "another-module" {}

declare module "module" {
    interface MyClass {
        MyFn(): someType
    }
}

if (MyClass.prototype.MyFn) throw new Error("'MyClass' already has the prototyped function 'MyFn'.")
MyClass.prototype.MyFn = someFn
```